# How to connect my sliding toggle button when pressed to the collapse or expand a picture

Tags: javascript, html, button, toggle

I'm trying to connect my toggle button to collapse and expand a picture when the button is pressed but I'm finding it difficult to achieve this. I would appreciate any help.

```
<label class="switch">
<input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
<span class="switch-label" data-on="hide" data-off="show"></span> 
<span class="switch-handle"></span> 
</label>

<img src="sit1eq.jpg" width="600px">  <!-- (image I want to hide and show) -->
```

You can find the CSS for the button on the JSFiddle.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KZ_TAMZ/mv9r5a3o/3/)

Comment: Are you using any library? Where are you getting the `data-on` and `data-off` attributes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you want to do is add some sort of event listener to the switch (in this case `input`) so when you check or uncheck the input, JavaScript can perform the action you want it to.

I modified your jsfiddle with some JavaScript (I added the jQuery library) with:

```
$('.switch-input').click((event) => {

  let _switch = $(event.target);

  if (_switch.is(':checked')) {
    $('img').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('img').show();
  }

});
```

And if you'd like to play around with the code, here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mv9r5a3o/30/

If you'd like some fancier effects than `show()` or `hide()`, feel free to change those around! Hope this helps out - and feel free to ask any questions!

Comment: i was just thinking in how would you make the picture default as hide so when you press the button it shows? do you just have to swap the hide() and show() tags around?
And just have to say thank you because thats what i was looking for

Comment: Yes, you'll want to switch the `hide()` and `show()` but you'll ALSO want to throw an `$('img').hide()` *ABOVE* the rest of that code. Here it is working: https://jsfiddle.net/mv9r5a3o/36/ (one thing to note: you _might_ want to change the text inside the toggle)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this JS to your fiddle:

```
// Get elements from the DOM
var checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName("switch-input")[0];
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

// Hide image by default
img.style.display = "none";

// Hide/show image on click depending on checkbox value
checkbox.addEventListener("click", e => 
  img.style.display = e.target.checked ? "block" : "none"
);
```

However, you almost certainly want to add ids to your DOM nodes because the getters I used are very brittle.

Comment: oooooh, you get a +1 from me because you didn't need to lean on jQuery like I did

Comment: I was just wondering I wanted the picture to be hidden as default and then when you toggle the button it appears? any idea how to do that>
thanks for the reply and i do appreciate you doing it without jquey as well which is a bonus

Comment: I'd suggest you include styling to `display:none;` the `img` to start. And then change the `img.style.display` portion to read like, `img.style.display = e.target.checked ? "none" : "block"` (that line changes the css from `display:none` to `display:block` and vice-versa)

Comment: Changed the default to hidden. It wasn't clear to me which behavior the OP wanted based on `data-on`, button text, and color of the switch indicators.